# Compare two lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

```
old = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('address','A45'),('type','00')]
new = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('type','01')]
```

I need to compare the `new` list against `old` one based on first element of the tuples, and show the difference between whatever elements `new` list has, so that the output should look like:

```
Match     : ver   =   1121
Match     : sign  =   89
Mismatch  : type  =   01 (old : 00)
```

I could get all the matching tuples with below list comprehension but could not think beyond it.

```
my_list = [(a,b) for (a,b) in new for (c,d) in old  if ((a==c) and (b==d))]
print( my_list)
```

Please suggest me a way to do it.

**EDIT**

I am sorry for not being clear on my question , I did not mention one more thing, the keys in the list can be repetitive, meaning the list can be like:

```
old = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('address','A45'),('type','00'),('ver','sorry')]

new = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('type','01'),('ver','sorry)]
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @holdenweb, I've made some changes to his code and this seems to be providing the expected output, please suggest if there are any flaws.

```
old = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('address','A45'),('type','00'),('ver','works?')]
new = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('type','01'),('ver','This')]

formatter = "{:12}: {:8} = {}".format
newfmter = "{} (old : {})".format

kv_old = []
for i,(kn, vn) in enumerate(new):
    vo = [(j,(ko,vo)) for j,(ko, vo) in enumerate(old) if (ko==kn) ]
    for idx,(key,val) in vo:
        if idx >=i:
            kv_old = [key,val]
            break;

    if kv_old[1]==vn:
        print(formatter("Match", kv_old[0], kv_old[1]))
    else:
        print(formatter("Mismatch", kn, newfmter(vn, kv_old[1])))
```

Comment: what would happen to `address`?

Comment: please suggest if any other way like traversing through the lists if not achievable by list comprehensions.

Comment: Since it is not in both the lists, nothing @MooingRawr

Comment: @MooingRawr the compare should work only with the items available in new

Comment: Does the ordering of the output matters? The order of the list for example:`ver` should come first, `sign` next

Comment: @MooingRawr yes, the order does matter, should be in same order as in new list.

Answer (score 13):

A `set` is a great tool for finding such mismatches:

```
>>> old = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('address','A45'),('type','00')]
>>> new = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('type','01')]

>>> print('no longer there:', set(old) - set(new))
no longer there: {('type', '00'), ('address', 'A45')}

>>> print('newly added:', set(new) - set(old))
newly added: {('type', '01')}

>>> print('still there:', set(old) & set(new))
still there: {('sign', '89'), ('ver', '1121')}
```

Comment: it's a tool OP can use to figure out the mismatch :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
n,o=dict(new),dict(old)
for i in n:
    print "{0:10}:{2:8} {3:8} {1}".format(*(("Match","") if o.get(i)==n[i] else ("Mismatch",o.get(i,i)))+ (i,n[i]))
```

Output:

```
Mismatch  :type     01       00
Match     :ver      1121     
Match     :sign     89
```

If you need the order, try to use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
n,o=OrderedDict(new),OrderedDict(old)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a list comprehension *isn't* the answer. This may be one of those times. Also, you don't handle the case where a key is present in `old` but not in `new` - I include that case here, though you can chop out that code if it isn't relevant. You could similarly handle the case of keys missing from `new`, but I didn't go that far.

```
old = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('address','A45'),('type','00')]
new = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('type','01'),("sneaky", 'not there before')]
formatter = "{:12}: {:8} = {}".format
newfmter = "{} (old : {})".format

for (kn, vn) in new:
    if any(ko==kn for (ko, vo) in old):
        ko, vo = [(ko, vo) for (ko, vo) in old if ko==kn][0]
        if vo==vn:
            print(formatter("Match", ko, vo))
        else:
            print(formatter("Mismatch", kn, newfmter(vn, vo)))
    else:
        print(formatter("New", kn, vn))
```

Comment: can we use the `enumerate()` to iterate through the both the lists to take care the repeating keys?

Comment: `enumerate` simply allocates numbers to the items in a sequence, so I'm not sure how it would help. But if the lists get large there are a number of possible ploys. The first to come to mind is to build, for each list, a dict whose keys are the tuples' first elements and whose values are the position of that tuple in the list. That would make it much quicker to determine the correct list element without iterating over it (which is an O(n/2) operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like :

```
old = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('address','A45'),('type','00')]
new = [('ver','1121'),('sign','89'),('type','01')]
my_list = [(a,b) for (a,b) in new for (c,d) in old  if ((a==c) and (b==d))]
for i in old:
     if i in my_list:
             print "Match : ", i
     else:
             print "Mismatch : ", i
```

that will give you :

```
Match :  ('ver', '1121')
Match :  ('sign', '89')
Mismatch :  ('address', 'A45')
Mismatch :  ('type', '00')
```

But for sure there is a more "pythonic" way....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner to get a list of all comparisons. Depending on how big your old and new lists are, a set comprehension would work a bit more quickly, but that speed would be nullified by my `sorted` + `itertools.groupby` approach below (as `sorted` returns a `list`):

```
comps = [(key, 'changed', old_val, new_val) 
          if old_val != new_val else (key, 'same', old_val)
           for key, old_val in old for oth_key, new_val in new
             if key == oth_key]
```

`comps` is now:

```
[('ver', 'same', '1121'),
 ('sign', 'same', '89'),
 ('type', 'changed', '00', '01')]
```

Print it out:

```
for t in comps:
    if len(t) == 3:
        print('%s: %s, value: %s' % (t[1], t[0], t[2]))
    else:
        print('%s: %s, value: %s' % (t[1], t[0], ', '.join(t[2:])))

same: ver, value: 1121
same: sign, value: 89
changed: type, value: 00, 01
```

Edit: The following isn't exactly what OP wants, but I'll leave it anyway for those interested in seeing what stayed the same first, and what changed second (actually, you could define a custom grammar to sort by if you wanted to see the elements that changed first, but that's up to you).

Prepare for using `itertools.groupby`, and taking into account OP's request for the printing order shown above, we can use a `collections.OrderedDict` object to create effectively an "ordered set" of "keys":

```
import collections

proper_order = tuple(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys([x[0] for x in new]).keys())

proper_order
Out[43]: ('ver', 'sign', 'type')
```

Now sort `comps` based on the custom grammar in `proper_order`:

```
comps_sorted = sorted(comps, key=lambda x: proper_order.index(x[0]))

comps_sorted
Out[45]: 
[('ver', 'same', '1121'),
 ('sign', 'same', '89'),
 ('type', 'changed', '00', '01')]
```

Use `itertools.groupby` to print:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(comps_sorted, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    for g in group:
        print('%s: %s' % (key, ', '.join(x for x in g if x not in ('same', 'changed'))))

same: ver, 1121
same: sign, 89
changed: type, 00, 01
```

It just so happens that the order of this output is the same as what OP requested above, but for larger cases, the difference in order between the two approaches will become evident.

Comment: What do you mean by "order matters?" You mean you need "same" before "changed?"

Comment: @not_a_robot, does it work if I have repeated keys in both the lists?
say, old and new lists have one more tuple  ('ver','blah')