# How can I subtract tuples from another tuple?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I have 2 sets of tuples with strings inside.

```
tuple_1 = ('A', '487')
          ('B', '42')
          ('A', '357')
          ('A', '440')

tuple_2 = ('A', '440')
          ('A', '440')
          ('B', '42')
          ('A', '503')
          ('A', '436')
```

I want to subtract tuple_1 from tuple_2 and get the output such that answer will contain the tuples which does not contain in tuple_2.

answer for the above one should be

```
tuple_answer = ('A', '487')
               ('A', '357')
```

`('A', '440')` and `('B', '42')` should get removed as it contains in both.
anybody has an idea, how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is not valid python code, please format it well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two lists of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256677/compare-two-lists-of-tuples)

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks, it goes close with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
tuple_1 = (('A', '487'),
          ('B', '42'),
          ('A', '357'),
          ('A', '440'))

tuple_2 = (('A', '440'),
          ('A', '440'),
          ('B', '42'),
          ('A', '503'),
          ('A', '436'))

print(tuple(set(tuple_1)-set(tuple_2)))
```

output:

```
(('A', '487'), ('A', '357'))
```

Comment: Thanks, thiis is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple([t for t in tuple_1 if t not in tuple_2])
```

Comment: This does not result in a tuple.

Comment: Yeah this does not result in a tuple.